# Notation for the automorphisms of a $S$-scheme over automorphisms of $S$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ct.category-theory, algebraic-groups, notation

Here is a slightly anecdotical notational question.

Let $S$ be a scheme and let $X$ be a scheme over $S$, with structural morphism $s\colon X\to S$. Is there a good suggestive notation for the group $\lbrace (f,g)\in \mathrm{Aut}(X)\times \mathrm{Aut}(S)~\vert~sf=gs\rbrace $ ?

After chatting with a categorical friend, this can be described succinctly as the automorphism group of $X\to S$ (considered as an object in the arrow category of schemes).

In fact, I'm interested in finding a good notation when $S$ is (the spectrum of) a field $k$ and $X$ is an affine algebraic group $G$ over $k$. I thought about using $\mathrm{Aut}(G\to k)$ or $\mathrm{Aut}(G\to \mathrm{Spec}(k))$, but there might be something more adapted or already existing in the literature.

Comment: Any notation including "$G\to k$" would be misleading.

Comment: You could also write $\operatorname{Aut}_{\operatorname{\underline{Sch}}^{\to}}(G \to \operatorname{Spec} k)$, but it might not be sufficiently standard that people immediately recognise it...

Comment: Thank you for your comments. @YCor , I really don't get why a notation including "$G\to k$" would be misleading. Is a notation including "$G\to \mathrm{Spec}(k)$" less misleading ?

Comment: No, $G\to Spec(k)$ is fine. $G\to k$ sounds like whatever kind of arrow from $G$ to $k$, which is not the case.

Comment: $\operatorname{Aut}(s)$?

Comment: @ThomasPoguntke: Probably most readers will associate $s$ with an object of the category of $S$-schemes, not the arrow category of the category of schemes. Hence this category should appear in the index, as suggested by R. van Dobben de Bruyn.

Comment: @Thomas That's an interesting suggestion, but it would then force me to always name the structural map $G\to \mathrm{Spec}(k)$, which would be too heavy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indeed, this already exists in the literature. The automorphisms of $G\to\mathrm{Spec}(k)$ are called *semilinear automorphisms* of $G$, or just *semi-automorphisms* of $G$, and the corresponding group is denoted by $\mathrm{SAut}(G)$. See Subsection 3.2 of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1207.1329) and references therein.

Comment: Thanks for those references ! I could access one of the reference therein, and it is quite interesting. Unfortunately, I could not access the other relevant reference, which is a paper of yours entitles "Abelianization of the second nonabelian Galois cohomology". Would it be possible to provide a copy of this paper ?

Comment: Please send me an e-mail, and I will send you the PDF file of the paper.

Comment: See also [this preprint](https://arxiv.org/abs/1608.07366) and the reference to Florence therein.

Comment: That's very kind to provide so many interesting references, I've also sent you a mail to obtain your paper. But I now realize that all those authors are in the situation where $k$ is a separably closed field $k_s$, and they only consider semilinear automorphisms over an automorphism of $k_s$ that fix an algebraic subextension, whereas I definitely don't want those restrictions. Well, I guess that if I insist on this difference, it wouldn't be bad to reuse that terminology.

Comment: See also [this preprint](https://arxiv.org/abs/1710.02471), Section 1.